# How do I extract a download link in R using rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I'm trying to extract the link to the .zip file from here:

> https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/tbl/csv/14100287-eng.zip

using the rvest package in R. The tables are updated monthly so I don't want to copy the link address into my R script each month.

I tried using the `SelectorGadget` tool to identify the CSS class by it doesn't seem on work on that site. I then tried to manually copy the xpath from the html script like this:

```
page=read_html("https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/tbl/csv/14100287-eng.zip")

dfile<-page %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="active active active active active active active active"]') %>% html_attr('href')
```

This worked perfectly for a short period but after a few days it began to return nothing (dfile is empty). I noticed the html script on the site had changed a bit (only two actives instead of 8) so I tried to adjust my script accordingly but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Are you sure that "https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/tbl/csv/14100287-eng.zip" points to an html ? It seems to me that it points to the zip file.

Comment: Yes. If you click on the link it should take you to the webpage which prompts you to click on a link to download the file. The link to the file is slighly different.

Comment: This is the link to the .zip file: https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/tbl/csv/14100287-eng.zip?st=b5Yqvs1n

Comment: I see... Well, when I run read_html('https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/tbl/csv/14100287-eng.zip') %>% write_html("example.htm"), the resulting example.htm is pure gibberish...

Comment: You're right it links directly to the .zip file. I'm not sure what happened here as this afternoon when I responded to your comment I clicked on the link and it took me to a webpage not the file. I had tired to download directly from the link before and it didn't work. Really sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No problems, mate. Let us know if page is an url -even an html form along with instructions how to fill it- that lists the link to your file.